# I can't seem to overlay maps with a transparent background in the map layout like I used to

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, print-composer, layouts

I have a workspace that I created maybe a year ago that was an evolution of a workspace I've used since before version 3, where I have 3 maps elements in a layout stacked in an overlay (to keep them centered on each other).

One is always a base image layer locked; another is some layer locked cadastral set (imagine roads over satellite image) and the third (top) is an atlas-controlled layer; say soil chemistry.

When I open this workspace in the 3.34 LTR or the nightly build (3.37) none of the overlays has a transparent background and defaults to white blocking out anything below.

I've turned off the background in the layout item property. I've tried with background enabled (shows whatever color I choose) and get no transparency even if I change the opacity.

I have overlays involved so that the maps center on each other. I tried all the combinations of overlay and not enabled and what not but no different.
I have rendering set to normal for the layer. Previously this would just stack the upper layer with no background.

I can get some kind of stacking with a multilply type rendering but the colors get very odd.
Am I missing some basic change recently?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error under 3.34 LTR. Could you provide a sample/mockup project for us to check?

Comment: I can't reproduce it either with the data  I have. I agree, I think you need to share more data (at the very least a screenshot). Some questions to narrow it down: does this work with all projects and layers, or only these ones? Does it work if you re-create the structure from scratch? And when was the last QGIS version where this worked for you? I wonder if this is a change in layer styling that didn't carry across properly (saved in a higher version, then opened and saved in a non-compatible lower version, then now opened again in a higher version).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I am going to try to rebuild the project. It is one I've evolved over >2 years. so It is likely something that fell through the cracks.
Also, I should have mentioned I am using an atlas to control layer visibility, though it is only one of the layers that is affected.

Comment: I just recreated a basic version of the layout + atlas that I had (even cheated by copying over to the new workspace and layout figured if it was still an issue I'd go from the ground up). The overlay issue is gone.  I guess something crept in there as @she_weeds suggested.
really appreciate the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @she_weeds for providing the essential clue.
Somehow the project was corrupted, and I need to recreate it. It seems copy-paste from old layouts (into a new workspace) is ok and dragging over layers (into a new workspace) is ok (at least for the few layers I have tried.